# Using Polly to run async task with timeout

Tags: c#, async-await, polly

I have a simple task that I would like to run in the background. The task should simply attempt to **move** a file. This task could fail because the file is in use in another process.

I would like to retry this action for a specified period of time and then `timeout` if the file is still locked.

I read about [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) and thought this would be ideal for my needs.

The code will eventually be included in an `ASP.NET` app but I've created a small **console** app in an attempt to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

This is my first attempt with [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) so I could be totally off the mark here, but as soon as I run the app in `Visual Studio 2013` I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

> Additional information: Please use asynchronous-defined policies when calling asynchronous ExecuteAsync (and similar) methods.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunMyTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task RunMyTask()
        {
            var timeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic, (context, span, arg3) => {});
            var policyResult = await timeoutPolicy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (!MoveFiles())
                    {
                    }
                });
            });
            if (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure && policyResult.FinalException is TimeoutRejectedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation Timed out");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation succeeded!!!!!");
            }
        }

        private static bool MoveFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                var origFile = @"c:\temp\mydb.sqlite";
                var tempFile = @"c:\temp\mydb.sqlite.tmp";
                File.Move(origFile, tempFile);
                File.Move(tempFile, origFile);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `async` variant of `Timeout` as well as the `async` execute method. Polly has `async` variants of each policy so you need to go `async` all the way.

```
TimeoutPolicy timeoutPolicy = Policy
  .TimeoutAsync([int|TimeSpan|Func<TimeSpan> timeout]
                [, TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic|Pessimistic]
                [, Func<Context, TimeSpan, Task, Task> onTimeoutAsync])
```

[From Timeout policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout)

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that! Works a treat now.

Comment: +1.  More detail on async executions in the Polly readme: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#asynchronous-support